# Determining if a function is negligible or not negligible

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Determining the following functions are negligible or not negligible.

Given a function $f:$$\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(n)=2^{-\log n+\log\log n-\log\log\log n}$. **My Answer: True (Negligible funciton)**

Could someone tell me if my above answer is correct or not.

I solved the above problem based on the following definition:

A **function is non-negligible** means that the function is bigger than **some** polynomial infinitely often: $\exists d: \varepsilon(\lambda) \geqslant 1/\lambda^d$

Saying that a **function is negligible** means that the function is smaller than **all** polynomials:

$\forall d, \lambda \geqslant \lambda_d: \varepsilon(\lambda) \leqslant 1/\lambda^d$

where $\lambda_d$ is some integer depending on $d$ and, in both cases, $\lambda$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying true or false has not much value unless you justify it a little bit.

Start examining the exponent and notice its dominant term is $\ln(n)$ since: $$\ln\ln\ln(n)))\ll\ln \ln(n)\ll\ln(n)$$

Thus $f(n)\sim 2^{-\ln(n)}$, that you can rewrite $\exp(-\ln(n)\ln(2))=n^{-\ln(2)}=\dfrac 1{n^{\ln(2)}}\approx \dfrac 1{n^{0.3}}$

Now to get a suitable $d$, just replace the approximations by inequalities according to the principle that if $\epsilon(n)\to 0$ then $|\epsilon(n)|<1$ for $n$ large enough.

Apply for instance to $\epsilon(n)=\dfrac{\ln\ln(n)-\ln\ln\ln(n)}{\ln(n)}$ and so on.

Comment: So, My answer is correct i.e. True

Comment: I shall say no, what about comparing it to $1/n^{0.2}$ and $1/n^{0.4}$ ? You can see the $\forall d$ is not satisfied.